# Replacing values at specific indexes within a list

Tags: python, list

If I have a list:

`characters = ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']`

and a string value

`letter = a`

and another list

`positions = [2, 3]`

How can I define a function that would replace the values of the list `characters` at the positions defined by `positions` with `letter` so that the output would be `['_', '_', 'a', 'a', '_']` ?

Comment: Do you know how to define any function at all?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a `for` loop:

```
characters = ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
positions = [2, 3]
letter = "a"

for position in positions:
    characters[position] = letter

print(characters)
# ['_', '_', 'a', 'a', '_']
```

Below is how to wrap it in a function. The function takes as arguments the original list, the indexes to make the changes, and the new character to insert. By iterating on the elements of `positions`, it will replace in the list by the `new_element` you provided, then return the modified version of this list. You can call this function with the variables defined above like this:

```
def replace_elements_in_list(my_list, positions, new_element):
    for position in positions:
        my_list[position] = new_element
    return my_list

my_new_list = replace_elements_in_list(characters, positions, letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a for loop. Iterate the `positions` list. Now, every iteration will represent the individual position. Replace the letter to the `characters` list. Your code:

```
def function():
    characters=["_","_","_","_","_"]
    letter="a"
    positions=[2,3]
    for i in positions:        #i values will be 2 and 3. Replace the letter a at position 2 and 3
        characters[i]=letter
    return characters

print(function())
```